# is there a interpretation for this dream?

Tags: halal-haram, dream

Asslamulaikum brothers and sister,

So my question is since a few month know I get to see a irritating dream of  being late to something and searching for clothes to wear (not naked) In this dream I am very stressed and under time pressure. Or similar scenario I am outside and searching for anything else any person and the dream feels so true.

Comment: This is off topic. Dream interpretation is against the Islam Q&A rules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about dream interpretation. See also https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/780/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, every dream teaches or tells something. What I think about this dream is that you rush to do things at the last minute. Also it is a reminder that there is not much time for any of us and  maybe that was what your dream was about. Also maybe you say that I will pray later and then you forget to or even if you just say that then you will be making a mistake because what if death comes to you at that moment as death will come for all of us. Then you will be accountable for that and remember that we will all enter our own grave.